# This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

Getting Error like this when opening a C# script from unity-3D on Visual Studio 2019.
Required  v4.7.1 which is already installed. I even tried changing it to 4.0, 4.5 and 4.8 but its still not working.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the unity tools? Does your vs open and work normally without asking things like pick an editor layout. Has it ever worked? What version of Windows? Is this a new unity project or an existing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried installing 2020.1.5f1 Unity3d without visual studio setup at first which led on missing few component on visual studio required to run the c# project.

I tried installing again without missing any component and it worked fine.